# Отправка фото на стену через VK Api wall.post (id паблика с минусом)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, requests, вконтакте

В общем, все методы и ссылки вроде как верные но attachments все равно не считывает, может беру id не тот, но я все перепробовал
(все делал по документации и id паблика с минусом)

```
att = f'photo{owner_id}_{response3["response"][0]["id"]}'
print(att)
response = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', headers = {'User-Agent':a},
    params={'access_token': token,
    'owner_id': owner_id,
    'from_group': 1,
    'attachments':att,
    'v':"5.131"}).json()
print(response)
```

вот что на выходе

```
photo-225116242_457248237
{'error': {'error_code': 100, 'error_msg': 'One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: invalid message param', ...
```

я не знаю что мне ещё сделать чтобы оно заработало